# BigQuery joins two tables and inserts data into another table

Tags: sql, database, google-bigquery, etl

I have two tables in BigQuery, `T1` and `T2`.

I want to join these two tables, and after joining, I have to insert the data into the `T3` table.

How is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try the [INSERT SELECT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#insert_select_statement) statement:

```
INSERT t3 (column1, column2)
SELECT t1.column1, t2.column2
FROM t1 join t2 on t1.id=t2.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save result of any query in a permanent table in BigQuery [Steps](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/writing-results#permanent-table).
When you write query results to a permanent table, the tables you're querying must be in the same location as the dataset that contains the destination table.